How to write script prefix braces with backslashes
I already posted add escape character with bash.
I need script to this for every line in a file that starts with {@codeBlock
so
{@codeBlock: TEstBigquerry.buildPicks}

should look like
\{@codeBlock:\ TEstBigquerry.buildPicks\}

My script
#!/bin/bash

file=clfields.mdx

while read -r line; do
  if [[ "${line::11}" == '{@codeBlock' ]]; then
    printf '%q\n' "$line"
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < clfields.mdx

Terminal output is ok but the file stays the same.
Why?

Don't use a shell read loop for this - see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Bash's printf %q does far more than escape braces. What's the actual quoting/escaping rule you need; i.e. what are you going to use the escaped output as input to?

Better not edit the question by adding a partial answer based on the answers. The real question here is: "I have a command that edits lines from the input. How do I run this command only on lines matching some pattern, but leave the other lines unchanged?"

Looks like a task better suited for awk

You could do the same thing as in the linked post (print with printf '%q\n'), but test each line:
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "${line::11}" == '{@codeBlock' ]]; then
      printf '%q\n' "$line" # quote out the line
    else
      printf '%s\n' "$line" # just print the line as it is
    fi
  done < input_file.txt

Explanation:

IFS= read -r line reads the whole line into the variable line.
${line::11} takes the first 11 characters of line.
< input_file.txt sends the contents of your input file to the while statement; you could also do cat input_file.txt | while read... to do the same thing.


take a look at my edit pls,the file stays the same,

@MikiBelavista Redirect the output to a new file and then rename the created file to the original name if you want to replace it.

@Kusalananda done ,perfect simple redirect.

That would be extremely slow compared to a sed/awk/perl/ruby/python script and do various different things to the input depending on the content of the input file. See why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and why-is-printf-better-than-echo.

with the default IFS, read -r line would drop leading whitespace (which you may or may not care about). Use IFS= read -r line to prevent that. But yes, doing this in the shell is going to be slow.

The echo "$line" would also do different things depending on the version of echo being used, whether "$line" started with -, whether it contained backslashes that could be interpreted as escape sequences like \t, etc.

These are good points. It does seem like the OP's question would include the leading whitespace, so I added the IFS=. If echo is problematic, is it better to just do printf '%s\n' "$line"?

I probably won't change the while read loop. I know it's slower than other ways of editing a file, but it's a very beginner-friendly syntax.

@wobtax it's not just slower, it's less portable, more fragile and just generally the wrong approach for what you're trying to do. It's important for beginners to learn the right way to do things even if the wrong way looks simpler (an extremely common issue in shell programming). And yes, printf '%s\n' "$line" is better than echo '"$line", see that link I provided in an earlier comment.

@EdMorton That's fair. Actually, if I were solving this specific task I would use awk instead of looping in the shell. But what's the "canonical" way to solve the more general task of "call a program on some of the lines, based on this condition"?

It depends on the problem we're trying to solve. Sometimes the solution is xargs calling a tool, sometimes it IS a simple while read loop calling another tool, sometimes it's a decorate-sort-undecorate approach with a shell loop or xargs in the middle, etc. For example if you have a 10,000 line input file within which you need to call md5sum for 5 lines, you would NOT write a shell loop reading all 10,000 lines but you might have a tool that splits the input, passes 5 lines to xargs or a shell loop then remerges it.

@EdMorton Thanks! Expanded on this question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787020/run-program-only-on-matching-lines

With sed:
sed 's/{/\\{/g;s/}/\\}/g' inputfile > outputfile

or
sed --in-place 's/{/\\{/g;s/}/\\}/g' inputfile


I tried your solution but it I got this
{@codeBlock: TestBigquery.buildPicks{

the ultimate brace should be changed,like I posted in my question.

@MikiBelavista I'm sure if you read the script and thought for a few seconds about what s/}/\\{/ might mean you could solve that problem yourself.

I don't think this quotes the characters Bash's printf %q does

Nothing in the question said anything about quotes, only prefixing braces with backslashes.

you're right, it originally didn't.

Using any awk:
$ awk '/^\{@codeBlock/ { gsub(/[{} ]/,"\\\\&") } 1' file
\{@codeBlock:\ TEstBigquerry.buildPicks\}

If you have GNU awk you can use awk -i inplace 'script' file to modify the input file, or with any awk (or any other command) awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file.

I don't think this quotes the characters Bash's printf %q does

@ilkkachu No it doesn't The OP didn't ask for a way to convert a string into something that could be passed as input to a Unix command (what %q does), they just asked for {, } and blank to be escaped which %q could do, in addition to other things the OP may find undesirable such as escaping $, or it could put them inside [] or whatever else the implementers think is reasonable now or in future to fulfill it's stated function.

Just because the OP accepted a previous answer using %q to escape {, } and blank doesn't mean it's a good idea or that there might not be better approaches.

I never said running printf in a while loop was too great an idea or that there wouldn't be better ways of doing it. But I am pointing out that they did use printf %q which this answer here appears to completely ignore, while producing output that is different from that produced by the code they already have.

@ilkkachu we get lots of questions with people asking how to do X and having implemented their attempted solution using some tool Y, that doesn't mean our answers have to also use Y. The OP just wants to escape a few characters across all lines in a file, we can all suggest whatever approach we like to doing that, we don't have to use printf %q or mimic it's full (and probably undesirable for the OPs needs) functionality.

again, I don't see anyone say one should use the same tools as they did. I don't know where you're getting that. I know they might not need the same functionality printf %q has, and it's quite possible they're never going to explain what it is they actually need. But, given they, as well as future readers, might not be that familiar on the specifics, it might be better for them to explain what the proposed solution does, especially if it's different from what the code seen earlier does.

@ilkkachu your comment was "I don't think this quotes the characters Bash's printf %q does". I've respond to your comment explaining why replicating printf %q functionality isn't required (and probably not even desirable), I don't think we need to discuss it further.

And if you'd just explained your reasoning on the functionality, and refrained from putting words in my mouth about using that exact tool, I wouldn't have had to correct you.
And also, if the answer here would explain what it does, and that it ignored the rest of the stuff %q does on purpose, it would have quite fine,
and much easier for a random reader to understand.

I know you don't need any awk code explained. I know a lot of regulars here know at least some awk.
But somewhat in line with what you said about posters choosing the wrong tools, they might also not be able to parse all the code in answers or guess the
logic of the more experienced folks without some help.
