Run program only on matching lines
Let's say I have a program blackbox, and a file with the following contents:
in this file
  this line contains =TAG=
    so does =TAG= this one
      as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
  =TAG= here again
    gone again

How do I run blackbox on only the lines containing =TAG=?
Note 1: One way is to use a while read loop, but this is considered bad practice. So what is the canonical, right way to do this (if there is one)?
Note 2: Of course, if I were just editing text, a solution with AWK or sed would be appropriate—but blackbox might have desired side effects. This question is for those situations where I need to execute another process.
Note 3: You might ask what happens if blackbox is something like nl or sort—where running it on multiple lines together has a different outcome from running a new process on each line.
In that case, I want to be able to do it each of these three ways:

Block-wise: replace each block of contiguous lines containing =TAG= with the result of blackbox on that block.
Expected output with blackbox = nl:
in this file
1  this line contains =TAG=
2    so does =TAG= this one
3      as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
1  =TAG= here again
    gone again


Line-wise: replace each line containing =TAG= with the result of blackbox on that line.
Expected output with blackbox = nl:
in this file
1  this line contains =TAG=
1    so does =TAG= this one
1      as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
1  =TAG= here again
    gone again


Continuously: send all the lines containing =TAG= to a blackbox process, and replace each block with the lines that would be newly printed before blackbox received the next block.
Expected output with blackbox = nl:
in this file
1  this line contains =TAG=
2    so does =TAG= this one
3      as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
4  =TAG= here again
    gone again

(If we used sort instead, all matching lines would end up sorted in the last matching block, because they wouldn't get printed until the end.)


I haven't found any questions on here asking about the general problem, but these are all special cases of this problem:

How to write script prefix braces with backslashes (line-wise)
Edit file based on existence of a string (line-wise)
Conditionally replace lines of file1 with the corresponding lines of file2 (line-wise)
Possible to speed this while read bash script up? (line-wise)
Replace string with contents of a file using sed (line-wise)
change newline with space on certain condition with sed (block-wise)
Sorting block of lines matching only the first one (block-wise)
Remove lines matching pattern, plus any lines following it matching a different pattern (block-wise)
Replace lines matching a pattern with lines from another file in order (continuously)
Something like `paste` but with a vertical alignment after a delimiter? (continuously)
Pass multiple command line arguments to an executable with text files (continuously)
Delete Nth line from each line matching a pattern (continuously)


You can execute another process in awk using getline, FWIW

Note that a while read loop is bad practice for processing text, it's not necessarily bad practice as part of sequencing calling of tools (that's what a shell exists to do). Where you run into a grey area is when you have a large file that you need to call a tool on just small parts of - that's when you need to decide whether to use a while read loop for part of it and, if so, how much of it and how you'll handle separating that part from the rest.

@EdMorton Thanks for your help and advice on improving the question—I wasn't really sure how far to generalize it, and I think I erred too far on the general side, i.e., "write me an encyclopedia entry for this type of problem." I do want to label the expected output more clearly, but otherwise I'll leave it as is.

With perl:
$ perl -ne '
  if (/=TAG=/) {
    STDOUT->flush;
    open $cmd, "|-", "nl" unless $cmd;
    print $cmd $_;
  } else {
    close $cmd;
    undef $cmd;
    print;
  }' file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     1    =TAG= here again
    gone again

$ perl -ne '
  if (/=TAG=/) {
    STDOUT->flush;
    open $cmd, "|-", "nl";
    print $cmd $_;
    close $cmd;
  } else {
    print;
  }' file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     1      so does =TAG= this one
     1        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     1    =TAG= here again
    gone again

$ perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -ne '
  if (/=TAG=/) {
    STDOUT->flush;
    unless ($cmd) {
      open $cmd, "|-", "stdbuf", "-oL", "nl";
      $cmd->autoflush;
    }
    print $cmd $_;
    usleep(10000)
  } else {print}' file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     4    =TAG= here again
    gone again

The latter assumes the command does not buffer its output (which we avoid for nl --actually ask for Line output buffering instead-- here with stdbuf -oL as found on GNU or FreeBSD systems), and that upon reading a line of input, produces the corresponding line(s) of output within the next 10,000 microseconds (0.1 second).
Here the command is hardcoded as "nl" or "stdbuf", "-oL", "nl" (which you could also write qw(stdbuf -oL nl)) inside the perl code. For a command and its argument to be passed as extra arguments to perl instead:
perl -ne '
  BEGIN {@cmd = @ARGV; @ARGV = ()}
  # rest of the code where the open call would become:
  open $cmd, "|-", @cmd
  ' stdbuf -oL nl < file

Instead of a simple command, you can make it any shell code by either using the code above and sh -c 'any shell code' as the simple command or use the open $cmd, "|any shell code" syntax¹

¹ Actually, in modern versions of perl, perl will skip executing a shell if the command is simple enough.

These work great, including the expected behavior if I replace nl with sort. I'm not familiar with perl—how do I set the variable $cmd?

@wobtax, the one you'd expect as hinted by the line(s). close $cmd waits for cmd to finish and that usleep(10000) is meant to give enough time for cmd to output what it has to output, you'd need to adjust if cmd may take longer.

Oops, I just deleted my comment because I answered my own question by trying it out. (The question was what it would do if the executable wrote more than one line per line.) Yep, works as expected!

Here's one way to do the first thing you asked for (Block-wise), assuming blackbox is nl:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "nl" }
    /=TAG=/ {
        print | cmd
        next
    }
    {
        close(cmd)
        print
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     1    =TAG= here again
    gone again

If you want to do it 1 line at a time as in your 2nd request (Line-wise), just move the close():
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "nl" }
    /=TAG=/ {
        print | cmd
        close(cmd)
        next
    }
    {
        print
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     1      so does =TAG= this one
     1        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     1    =TAG= here again
    gone again

GNU awk also supports Coprocesses if you need more control over where the output of the external command appears in the overall output or it needs any other additional processing before printing it.
And talking of which... here's a way to implement your 3rd request, Continuously, using GNU awk for coprocesses:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "nl" }
    { lines[NR] = $0 }
    /=TAG=/ {
        print |& cmd
        tbds[NR]
    }
    END {
        close(cmd, "to")
        for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            if ( i in tbds ) {
                if ( (cmd |& getline line) > 0 ) {
                    lines[i] = line
                }
            }
            print lines[i]
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     4    =TAG= here again
    gone again

That assumes your input isn't so massive that it can't fit in memory. If that's not the case then you can do the same thing with a 2-pass approach reading the input twice instead of storing it in the lines[] array.
The above might break if the pipe fills up (thanks @Stéphane Chazelas for pointing that out), if your system has stdbuf then you can do the following to make nl output line-buffered:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "stdbuf -oL nl" }
    /=TAG=/ {
        print |& cmd
        if ( (cmd |& getline line) > 0 ) {
            $0 = line
        }
    }
    { print }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     4    =TAG= here again
    gone again

With a non-GNU awk you can write to a temp file instead of piping to a process and then read from the tempfile instead of reading from the process, e.g.:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

tmp="$tmp" awk '
    BEGIN {
        tmp = ENVIRON["tmp"]
        cmd = "nl > \047" tmp "\047"
    }
    { lines[NR] = $0 }
    /=TAG=/ {
        print | cmd
        tbds[NR]
    }
    END {
        close(cmd)
        for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            if ( i in tbds ) {
                if ( (getline line < tmp) > 0 ) {
                    lines[i] = line
                }
            }
            print lines[i]
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
in this file
     1    this line contains =TAG=
     2      so does =TAG= this one
     3        as =TAG= does this other line
    this line does not
nor does this line
     4    =TAG= here again
    gone again

or, again, use stdbuf in the same way as we do for the coprocess solution.
If you're ever considering using getline make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first.

Your co-process approach will deadlock when the pipes get full as you're only getting the output in the end. That and the tmp-file alternative also assume that cmd produces one line of output for each line of input.

Note that -v tmp="$tmp" assumes $TMPDIR doesn't contain backslash characters. \047 assumes an ASCII-based system.

@StéphaneChazelas thanks. I fixed the tmp name issue, and I'm OK with leaving the \047 for ASCII ', I expect anyone on a non-ASCII system can figure out the equivalent or another way to ensure the shell doesn't interpret the tmp file name if there's an issue. As for the co-process filling up the pipe - fair enough, I've added a fix for that after reading your perl script. And yes, I'm assuming 1 line of output from the command for 1 line of input.

Yeah, this rules! For the continuous one, the way I imagined it in the case where k lines map to k'>k output lines, we tell the script: “while you process these k lines, if blackbox prints anything now, put those lines here.” So for example if blackbox were the awk script { print $0; print $0 }, the continuous variant would be identical to the block-wise variant. If it were sort, all the matching lines would go at the end.

Are you saying that you'd WANT all the lines to go at the end? Actually, I see you accepted an answer to this question so please just ask a new question with an example demonstrating your requirements.

That was what I was picturing (sort as a degenerate case). On the other hand, your interpretation is pretty reasonable—replace the nth input line with the nth output line—and my example output didn't really disambiguate between those two interpretations, so I see where you're coming from.
